# installing mod_brotli in centos apache

Tags: apache, centos, brotli

I am having troubles installing brotli on a centos machine. I've checked the [docs for brotli](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_brotli.html) and apparently it is available in version `2.4.26` and later. I am running a `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS 7)`.

I may be misunderstanding what available means, because there no mention of `mod_brotli` in `/etc/httpd/modules`. I am googling like a complete idiot, and all the hits suggest installing it from source, while accorcing to apache docs, it is `available`.

I've run `yum search brotli` and found package `php72-php-brotli.x86_64 : Brotli Extension for PHP`. However, I am not sure what PHP has to do with file compression, so that might not be the correct package.

So what is the preferred way to install brotli on centos machine running apache?

Comment: If it is available in version 2.4.26 and later, and you are  running 2.4.6, then it is expected that you don't have it (2.4.26 is newer than 2.4.6 because 26>6 :)

Comment: Aaahhhh, those aren't decimals? Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Those are decimals. That’s how decimal counting works :-) Instructions on how to install from source here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/brotli/

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is available in version 2.4.26 and later.
2. install brotli

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/google/brotli.git
   $ cd brotli
   $ ./configure-cmake
   $ make && make install
   ```
3. recompile apache

   ```
   $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache/ --enable-brotli --with-brotli=/usr/local
   $ make && make install
   ```